# How to access the "key" property from a reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

How can I access the `key` property of a component.  I thought it would be in this.props but it's not.

e.g.

```
<ProductList
    key = {list.id}
    listId = {list.id}
    name = {list.name}
    items = {list.items}
/>
```

and in product list if I do

`console.log(this.props)`

returns

```
Object {listId: "list1", name: "Default", items: Array[2]}
```

With no key property at all.  I can create another property and assign the same value to it, but it seems redundant since the key property is already being used.

Also, does the key property have to be unique in the entire component, or just in the loop or collection it's being rendered from?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The `key` property is used by React under the hood, and is not exposed to you. You'll want to use a custom property and pass that data in. I recommend a semantically meaningful property name; `key` is only to help identify a DOM node during reconciliation, so having another property called `listId` makes sense.

The `key` property does not need to be unique for the whole component, but I believe it should be unique for the nesting level you're in (so generally the loop or collection). If React detects a problem with duplicate `key`s (in the development build), it will throw an error:

> Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `.$a`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.

Comment: if it is not supposed to be exposed to the consumer (developer), then why do we have to generate unique keys ourselves? Couldn't react do this for us upon instantiation of the object?

Comment: @JasonFB React can create unique keys, but it cannot create consistent keys across different render calls (used when reordering the elements).

Comment: ah yes i see. so in a server-client architecture it is preferable to use the server-generated key (like the database's primary key, for example) ?

Comment: @JasonFB Yes, anything that will be consistent is ok, and server-generated primary keys work great

Comment: so… I've started passing components both a `key=` (for React) and also an `id=`, which happens to be identical on a record-by-record basis (`key={1} id={1}`) … this works fine but seems repetitive tome.

Comment: I can understand why it feels repetitive. It might help to remember that one prop is for your app logic and the other is for React, they just happen to have the same value.

Comment: Yes, it does feel repetitive!"While this may seem redundant, it’s important to separate app logic from reconciling hints" An excerpt from here: https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `ref` is also another special  prop just like `key` which are used by React, and are **not** forwarded to the component.

Answer (score 54):

**Key** : `this._reactInternalFiber.key`

**Index** : `this._reactInternalFiber.index`

Comment: This answer is for those who really want to access the key not looking for an advice

Comment: Keep in mind that this is accessing React internals. The React team can rename/delete `_reactInternalFiber` with no notice and without marking it as a breaking change.

Comment: does this work for function components?