# Use the key as a prop in a Child Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a list of elements in React, using the key of the element as an index in front of each item. But using props.key just returns `undefined`. Any ideas how to access the key property?

This is the parent:

```
{options.map((option, index) => {
 return (
  <Option
   key={index + 1}
   optionText={option}
  />
 );
})}
```

This is the child:

```
const Option = props => {
 const option = props.optionText;
 const myKey = props.key;
 return (
  <div className="option">
   {myKey} {option}
  </div>
 );
};
```

Comment: pass another props like : Key and then use it in child component

Comment: @mjsameri Is there no way to access it directly?

Comment: Same question with good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682774/how-to-access-the-key-property-from-a-reactjs-component

Comment: I dont think so my friend

Comment: @eladfrizi Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was loking for! How can I close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key is reserved by React. You need to add another prop with a different name.

https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html