# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Key prop doesn't show when inspect element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My `ListItem.js`looks like this:

```
render() {
        return(
            <li key={parseInt(this.props.keyProp)}>
                <button onClick={this.props.onClick} 
                    className="sidebar__button">
                        {this.props.text}
                </button>
            </li>
        );
    }
```

When I separately place {parseInt(this.props.keyProp)}, it shows a number.
But when I equate it to key property of the `<li>`, I get the error `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` and I also cannot see any key when I inspect element on the `<li>`.

I am sharing the code which uses `ListItem.js`

```
populateLi = () => {
        let LIs = []
        for (var keyItem in graphs) {
            if (graphs.hasOwnProperty(keyItem)) {
                LIs.push(<ListItem keyProp={keyItem} onClick={this.onClick} text={graphs[keyItem][0]["Scheme Name"]}/>)
            }
        }
        return LIs;
    }
```

Comment: what is the value of `this.props.keyProp`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682774/how-to-access-the-key-property-from-a-reactjs-component

To be brief, key is used by react under the hood to optimize the performance. Look at the second answer in the stackoverflow link I posted

Comment: make sure `parseInt(this.props.keyProp)` does return a value and does returns a different value for each list item.

Comment: Why do you use `parseInt`? React expects a key to be a _**string**_, not number. If `parseInt` receives non-numeric value, it returns NaN. That's most likely why you get that warning.

Comment: Yes, key is supposed to be a string. The problem persists even when I remove `parseInt`

Comment: As the warning message suggests, keys should be _**unique**_. Your ones are obviously not unique. That' why.

Comment: I have shared some more code, maybe it's easier to find the mistake now.

Answer (score 1):

The `key` prop should be added to the function that is responsible for rendering `ListItem.js`. So:

`items.map((item) => KeyItem key={item.id} item={item} />`

Answer (score 0):

As per the react documentation, the "key" prop is a special **string** attribute that is used for optimization and identification. It does not appear in the HTML.

The error you are getting is due to the fact that each list element does not have a unique key. This should be fixed by assigning a unique key to each element.

More info here: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

The key is supposed to be `ListItem` itself not on the `<li>` inside `ListItem`

```
LIs.push(<ListItem key={keyItem} onClick={this.onClick} text={graphs[keyItem][0]["Scheme Name"]}/>)
```

That fixes the problem.