# trying to acces the key property passed to other component, but in the component it is passed

Tags: reactjs

I am in a component `TodoList` and rendering an component `TodoItem` in it. But i need to have access to the props that I've passed to the `TodoItem`, to set my state with the item clicked, for me to edit the task.

```
    onEdit = () => {
        this.setState({
            edit: true,
            create: false,
            selected: this.props.key
        });

    };

    const renderList = (
        list.map(item => (
            <TodoItem onEdit={this.onEdit} onCompleted={this.onCompleted.bind(this)} key={item._id} title={item.title} completed={item.completed}/>
        ))
    );
```

Comment: Please provide a better description

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the "key" property from a reactjs component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682774/how-to-access-the-key-property-from-a-reactjs-component)