# Missing key for a child element in a list, although assigned

Tags: html, reactjs

I have the following single task(todo) `<li>` element being rendered and returned:

```
class TaskContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="task-container" key={Date.now()}>
        <DeleteTaskButton />
        <Task text={this.props.text} />
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

However, this is the returned element, with no key associated with:

```
<li class="task-container">
```

It seems like it didn't assign the "key" prop.
I might be missing something here, please let me know why this doesn't work?
Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Key is not part of the output in React

Comment: Thanks @squillman!

Answer (score 1):

`key` is an internal react property used to help re-render components. It will not display in the DOM.  Use another property if you need it to be attached to the element.

[Here is a more in depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682774/how-to-access-the-key-property-from-a-reactjs-component)

Comment: Thanks @Hozeis!
This partially solved my issue, I still had to create a "key" prop because I got a warning message for missing key in child list element.
I used a different unique id with "id" prop to track the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.
I extracted a component and tried to assign an explicit key.
Instead, I should have assigned the key with `<TaskContainer key={some_key}/>`
[This](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:%7E:text=Extracting%20Components%20with%20Keys) solved my issue.