# Testing react hook using Vitest and React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, vitest

I am testing react hooks using Vitest and React Testing Library in a way shown below.

The hook make use of `useEffect` hook to load the script, My use-case is if hook renders properly and loads the script.

I mocked `useLocale` as its being used inside the useAnalytics() hook.

```
import React from 'react';

import { vi, describe, it } from 'vitest';

import { useAnalytics } from './useAnalytics';

vi.mock('@hooks/useLocale', () => ({
  useLocale: vi.fn(() => 'en')
}));

vi.spyOn(React, 'useEffect');

describe('useAnalytics', () => {
  it('render useAnalytics', () => {
    // downloadAppEvent is one of the function that this hook returns. 
    const { downloadAppEvent } = useAnalytics();
  });
});
```

I have also tried using the below approach.

```
renderHook(() => useAnalytics())
```

then I get `ReferenceError: document is not defined`, probably I am using next.js that’s why.

Answer (score 2):

Reagarding `ReferenceError: document is not defined`, it sounds like you haven't properly configured your vitest environment. Try adding this in your vite.config.ts (if you are using a shared config for vite and vitest):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'; // if you are using a shared config, make sure to change this import from 'vite'


export default defineConfig({
  // ... stuff here
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom', // This right here
  }
});
```

You will also need to install jsdom as a devDependency for this to work. This should get rid of the ReferenceError you mention.

You can also change the environment per test file, read more about it here: https://vitest.dev/config/#environment

If I may add a suggestion: read up on the testing philosophy of unit testing and testing-library/react specifically. When I started testing React apps, I was trying to assert that a component receives a certain "key" as prop and wrote a question on StackOverflow on this. One of the responses I got was that "Testing implementation details in unit tests is typically an anti-pattern." ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758600/how-can-i-assert-which-value-has-been-passed-to-a-li-key-attribute-in-react-wi#comment123306467_69758600)) and I think this applies to spying on React's useEffect as well.